# arbitrary length regex?

Tags: regular-expression

a weird question that i can't seem to solve

i want to do a search and replace,

anything that says

```
%d, %3d, %13d
```

or anything like that i want to replace it with XXX
I'm not sure how to deal with any arbitrary number of numbers in between % and d.. is there anyway i can do this? for even something absurd like

```
%000010d
```

I have tried to go about something like

```
%s/%...\dd\|%..\dd\|%.\dd\|%\dd\|%d/XXX/g
```

to try and solve it each case at a time but I figured there's a better way to do a search and replace.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JimStewart You should write that as an answer.

Comment: @JimStewart If you added it as an answer we could upvote it so you can start earning the rep you need to close it ;) (I mean literally just paste it in: it's concise, but it fully answers the question.)

Comment: @solobyy you might have a look [here](http://vimregex.com/) to familiarize yourself with some of things that vim regex can do.

Answer (score 3):

This will match any number of digits before the `d`:

```
:%s/%\d*d/XXX/g
```

`\d` matches any digit, `*` matches 0 or more times.

See `:h pattern.txt` for all things regex.